# How to place a condition on a variable

Tags: r

I have a sampling function of:

```
z = rnorm(n, 0.3, 1)
```

And would like my variable `f` to equal `1` if `-pi < z_i < pi` and equal `0` otherwise.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. My other idea was to use a `reject` function but this seems overly complicated.

Comment: `z <- abs(rnorm(n, 0.3, 1))<pi`

Comment: @DanY Very close, you needed to convert Boolean to Integer.  `f <-  +abs(rnorm(n, 0.3, 1))<pi`

Comment: I suppose adding the `+` gets exactly what the OP requested.  But R converts boolean to integer/double anytime you use a boolean in a mathematical expression. The only time I would store a boolean explicitly as 0/1 is if I needed to display the data and that display was horizontally constrained.  But maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use the function `ifelse`, which does exactly what you want: to return a value if a condition satisfies, and another different if not. For example, for n= 10 and pi=1:

```
f = ifelse (rnorm(n=10, 0.3, 1) > 1,1,0)
```

You should easily figure out how to solve your problem with this example.

You could also save your results in a temporal vector, and then check the exact condition you want with boolean operators:

```
ri = rnorm(n=10, 0.3, 1)
ifelse(-1 < ri & ri < 1,1,0)
```

Following @M-M comment, you can also obtain values of 1 or 0 just from the evaluated conditional expression. For instance:

```
as.integer(-1 < ri & ri < 1)
```

Comment: You don't need `ifelse`. Boolean can be converted to integers. And just couple days ago *Emma Haruka Iwao* calculated pi to 31.4 trillion decimal places. https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2019/03/14/google-employee-breaks-guinness-world-record-calculating-trillion-digits-pi/?utm_term=.49e0aa0d838b ... let's set pi to 3.14 at least. p.s. ***`pi` is already in r!!!*** ;)

Comment: You're right, but assuming OP is learning the basics I feel this can provide an easily generalizable solution. Happi-pi day!!

Comment: I am sorry to push further. But assigning values to the reserved parameters is bad practice. I strongly recommend deleting `pi = 1` line. Besides that, consider flagging for duplicates for these kind of questions instead of posting an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created the variable `z`, then you can do this with `ifelse()`:

```
f <- ifelse(abs(z) < pi, 1, 0)
```

Or with:

```
f <- as.integer(abs(z) < pi)
```

The second one might be quicker, although you probably won't notice unless `n` is large.

EDIT: The second one is much faster: just checked it on a vector of 1,000,000 values and the first takes 0.2 seconds, the second method shows `elapsed 0`!

Comment: `elapsed 0`? do you mind sharing your bench-marking? p.s  there is a library called [`microbenchmark`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/microbenchmark/versions/1.4-6/topics/microbenchmark) in r. That's a better practice for comparing different methods. p.s.2. second one is faster!

Comment: Yes you're right: I was about to leave the office and just ran it once! Running on `microbenchmark` gives median times of 94 and 9 milliseconds respectively, so the `f <- as.integer(abs(z) < pi)` is definitely a lot faster.